# How do I make a small pmatrix?

Tags: fontsize, matrices

I want a small matrix but the only command I can find is `\smallmatrix` which leaves the brackets out. Is there a simliar one that includes brackets?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you use `mathtools` package, I believe there is a `psmallmatrix` or `smallpmatrix` environment.

Answer (score 22):

Three possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\SmallMatrix[1]{{%
  \tiny\arraycolsep=0.3\arraycolsep\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}}

\begin{document}

$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

$\begin{psmallmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{psmallmatrix}$

\SmallMatrix{1&2&3\\1&2&3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

It's easy to define one:

```
\newenvironment{psmallmatrix}
  {\left(\begin{smallmatrix}}
  {\end{smallmatrix}\right)}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{psmallmatrix}
  {\left(\begin{smallmatrix}}
  {\end{smallmatrix}\right)}

\begin{document}

Here is a small matrix $\begin{psmallmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{psmallmatrix}$, 
that is, the identity matrix.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need to use `\left(` and `\right)` in this case: `(` and `)` produce the same size...

Comment: @Mico This is one of the rare cases where I recommend them; if the matrix has more than two rows they're necessary.

Comment: You're right, of course. :-) Typesetting a small matrix with *three or more* rows would seem to defeat the whole purpose of having a small-matrix-environment to begin with.

Comment: @Mico I'd be very careful before using an inline `smallmatrix` with more than two rows, but sometimes this could be a good compromise.

Comment: @egreg if the sentence must end with a `3x3` matrix, would you recommend the use of `psmallmatrix` or would you go for the display mode?

Comment: @manooooh Probably I'd go with a display.

Answer (score 15):

You mention `pmatrix` in the title of your posting, but you refer to "brackets" rather than "parentheses" later on, so I'll assume for now that you're interested in a small matrix surrounded be square brackets.

To create a small matrix surrounded by square brackets, you could either use the `bsmallmatrix` environment, which is provided by the the `mathtools` package, or "roll your own", so to say, by enclosing a `smallmatrix` environment inside `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`:

[image]

You'll notice that the latter matrix is surrounded by larger brackets than is the former, which features the basic size of the `[` and `]` square brackets. Your call as to which one looks better...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bsmallmatrix' environment
\newenvironment{brsm}{% % short for 'bracketed small matrix'
  \bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix} }{%
  \end{smallmatrix} \bigr]}
\begin{document}
$x\begin{bsmallmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bsmallmatrix}x$
vs.\ 
$x\begin{brsm}1&2\\3&4\end{brsm}x$
\end{document}
```

Comment: One might add that the mathtools package also defines smallmatrix* and p(/b/B/v/V)smallmatrix* environments which accept an alignment parameter.

Comment: @Bernard - I agree with you. I was trying mostly to address the OP's specific question, so that's why I the limited the length of my answer. Of course, should the OP feel like exploring the many capabilities of the `mathtools` and `amsmath` packages, I'd be delighted.

Comment: @Mico, `\left[` and `\right]` would be better than `\bigl[` and `\bigr]`.

Comment: @Spectorsky - I *strongly disagree* with your claim that using `\left[` and `\right]` would be "better". To wit, using `\left[` and `\right]` would produce the *exact same output* as employing the `bsmallmatrix` environment would. The point of using `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` in the definition of the `bsrm` environment was to provide a different "look" from `bsmallmatrix`. Or is there a point in "re-inventing" the wheel, ummm, the `bsmallmatrix` environment?

Comment: @Mico, sorry, I don't use mathtooldss package, so I haven't `bsmallmatrix` env. If 'standard' look doesn't fit, of course your way is exact tuning with `\bigr` or `\biggr`.

Comment: Just as a point of information, apparently in the Commonwealth "(round) brackets" means what are called "parentheses" in the US.  I've been hit by that in the past too.

Comment: @kcrisman - Thanks for this. I'm definitely guilty as charged for associating the terms parentheses with round, brackets with square, and braces with curly. :-)